# How to use .formatted(.percent) with specified precision? (FormatStyle protocol)

Tags: swift, formatting, format

I want to convert a progress's `Double` value ranging from 0 to 1 into a formatted `String` with a selected amount of fraction digits, e.g. **0.789123456** to "**79,1 %**".

Added challenge: I want to use Foundation's new [`FormatStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/formatstyle) protocol method `.formatted()`.

To my surprise, I can't get it to work. I can't find a way to *specify the precision*.

```
var progress: Double = 0.789123456
progress.formatted(.percent) // "78,9123456 %" it starts so easy
progress.formatted(.number.precision(.fractionLength(1))) // "0,79"
progress.formatted(.number.precision(.fractionLength(0...1))) // "0,79"
progress.formatted(.number.precision(.fractionLength(0...1))).formatted(.percent) // does not compile
// "Instance method 'formatted' requires the types 'FloatingPointFormatStyle<Double>.FormatOutput' (aka 'String') and 'FloatingPointFormatStyle<Double>.Percent.FormatInput' (aka 'Double') be equivalent"

Double(progress.formatted(.number.precision(.fractionLength(1)))) // nil
Double("0.79")?.formatted(.percent) // "79 %", gotcha, I have german Locale!

Locale.current // "en_DE (current)"
Locale.current.decimalSeparator // ","

Double(progress.formatted(.number.precision(.fractionLength(1))).replacingOccurrences(of: Locale.current.decimalSeparator!, with: ".")) // "0,8"
Double(progress.formatted(.number.precision(.fractionLength(1))).replacingOccurrences(of: Locale.current.decimalSeparator!, with: "."))?.formatted(.percent) // "80 %"
```

Is there a way to do it with `FormatStyle`? Or do I have to go with the old `NumberFormatter` and its `maximumFractionDigits`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `.formatted(...)` you first choose what format style to use, in this case `FormatStyle.Percent`

```
progress.formatted(.percent)
```

and then you can configure this format style to your liking

```
progress.formatted(.percent.precision(.fractionLength(1)))
```

Another example with a rounding rule

```
progress.formatted(.percent.precision(.fractionLength(1)).rounded(rule: .down))
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks for this info. (Voted.) Where is this documented? All I can find is a very cryptic mention of it in the BinaryFloatingPoint protocol, with in information about things like `fractionLength`.

Comment: [Decimal.FormatStyle.Percent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal/formatstyle/percent), scroll down to Instance Methods. But I must admit that I have used Xcode autocomplete a lot when learning about the new formatting, typing `.percent.` and then examining what shows up in the suggestion list.

Comment: What other FormatStyles are there? I see `.Currency`. Are there others?

Comment: A more general .number and I also think there is one for Measurement but the ones I have used are number, percent and currency

Comment: And how do you get currency to work? It has a "code" parameter. What does that want? Can you control the number of decimal places? The docs... leave a lot to be desired.

Comment: You need to supply a 3 letter currency code but otherwise it works like the others so you use the same .precision as above for instance

Comment: Thanks Joachim, works perfectly! I must have gotten confused in the nested brackets, seems so easy now, again.